# ICollectionView CurrentChanging Cancel

Tags: wpf, icollectionview

I try to cancel CurrentChanging event like shown in this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionview.currentchanging

But, I have `e.IsCancelable` = FALSE. This property only has a getter and I dunno what can I do to set this property to TRUE. Any Idea?

Comment: `e.IsCancelable` is meant to give information about this event is cancelable or not. it cant be changed in the event. What's your exact requirement?

Comment: As I said, I try to cancel CurrentChanging on CollectionView. But common task is cancel SelectionChange on DataGrid (exactly, I want to cancel SelectionItem change from SelectionChange event handler / command).

Comment: From SelectionChanged event? It's normal to unable cancel accomplished fact. Perhaps you would be more interesting in SelectionChanging event.